# Is there a way to reach the classic settings in Unifis overlay?

Tags: networking, router

Since the last update I was no longer able to view the old settings. However the new overlay does no longer allow to set vlans for wlans.
Is there a way to reach the old overlay, or am I stuck with the new design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach the old Design over Settings -> System Settings -> New User Interface
After disabling the option and applying your changes, you will have the old overlay back.

For the new design you can create a new network and tag this network on your new Wifi.